# Custom validation in a CUSTOM Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've a custom django admin that extends a default change_form (I do it because a need some logic for uploading images), but I need a way to show the page again if no image was uploaded, and show the errors. Some code to illustrate:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    main_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, related_name='collage')
```

I extend the **change_form.html** admin template for this model:
`myapp/templates/admin/mymodel/change_form.html`

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
 {% block inline_field_sets %}
  {% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
   {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
  {% endfor %}
 <fieldset class="module">
  <h2>Upload photos</h2>
  <h3>Main photo</h3>
   <input name="main_photo" type="file" />
  <h3>Others</h3>
  <input name="photos" type="file" multiple />
 </fieldset>
{% endblock inline_field_sets %}
```

Now I overwrite the `save_model` method from `ModelAdmin` in the `admin.py`

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    exclude = ['main_photo', 'photos']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        photos = request.FILES.getlist('photos')
        main_photo = request.FILES.get('main_photo', None)
        if not main_photo:
            pass # --> I NEED THE WAY TO NOTIFY THE USER THIS IMAGE MUST BE UPLOADED
            # raise ValidationError("msg") --> It's not an option because this doesnt show the form re-rendered with the error.    
        # some internal business logic here: 
        folder_to_save = '{0}/{1}'.format(self.folder_to_save_img, obj.id)
        obj.main_photo = Photo.objects.create(folder=folder_to_save, original=main_photo)
        obj.save()
        if photos:
            for photo in photos:
                obj.photos.add(Photo.objects.create(folder=folder_to_save, original=photo))
```

Comment: why doing it that hand-made-custom-crazy-way instead of giving a try one of djanog dedicated libraries for handling that and giving you for free support for django admin? give a try to https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails or smth https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/gallery/

Comment: You need to create a `Form` (or `ModelForm`) and do the setup and validation there (required fields, any extra validation in `clean` methods). Then you configure the `ModelAdmin` to use that form.